# Create nested dict by adding column values of pd.DataFrame as keys to an existing dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict

```
dict={'6': [0.11, 10],
 '3': [0.20, 30],
 '2': [0.25, 22]}
```

and a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'ID':'10', 'count':100}, {'ID':'11','count':90}, {'ID':'12','count':80}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
```

and I want to merge them into a nested dict such that the ID column of the dataframe serves as the key (the second column of the dataframe is not important):

```
nested_dict={'10':{'6':[0.11, 10]}, '11':{'3':[0.20, 30]}, '12':{2: [0.25, 22]}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your requirement is probably not possible without redefining the data structure being used. Dictionaries, by definition are unordered data structures. If there is no natural key b/w the dataframe and the dictionary, order is the only gauranteed way to link them correctly. And since your data is a dictionary, the link is not possible. you might want to take a step back, and, if possible, modify the first data structure to an `OrderedDict` or a nested list. The dictionary can't directly be changed to another data type with gaurantee of order.

Comment: Try `nested_dict = {ID: {key: dct[key]} for ID, key in zip(df.ID, dct)}` (`dict` renamed in `dct` because `dict` is taken).

Comment: @Timus That worked. Thanks.